# Where should rookie go for best SQL tutorial resources?

Tags: sql

I´m interested in both web resources and books. It´s a jungle out there, please give me a hand.

My goal is to **learn the SQL language** so I can **query Sql Server** databases within a couple of weeks.

I´ve got a programming background, and I know some basic stuff about relational databases, but almost nothing on how to use the SQL language.

---

Thanks to you ALL for all good tips! I will save this page as a starting point in my mission to learn SQL. Sadly enough it´s not possible to set more than one answer as "accepted"...

Comment: I really liked http://www.sqlzoo.net. It's free and very helpful.

Comment: I like more official places like this. After all IBM is the entity that invented SQL: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.50.0/com.ibm.sqlt.doc/sqlt.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't normally go for the ' ... in 21 days' books but this online one seems reasonable: [Teach Yourself SQL in 21 Days, Second Edition](http://www8.silversand.net/techdoc/teachsql/index.htm).

See [Where can I find training/tutorials for SQL and T-SQL?](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=694)

Comment: Thanks Mitch, I liked that book!

Comment: I would like to point out that the first link is currently dead, as of 9/17/2017.

Answer (score 1):

one of my favorite websites to get started with SQL is : [SQLCourse](http://www.sqlcourse.com/)

Good luck for your starting

Answer (score 0):

[This (w3schools)](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) is always a nice place to start.

Comment: plus 1, Pretty up-to-date and exhaustive resource with nice examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try [SQL Exercises](http://www.sql-ex.ru)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps You need to begin your own project, It is always recommended when learning something new that you fight with real problems.

http://www.databasejournal.com/ is one of good recurses,